# How to find branch cuts and branch points of $\sqrt(z^a +1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, branch-cuts, branch-points

I have tried to find out the branch cuts and branch points of the function $\sqrt(z^a +1)$, where $0<a<2$. The function can be written as $e^{\frac{1}{2}(\log(z^a+1))}$ and from here I have concluded following:

Branch points: $\{z: z^a+1=0\}$ and branch cuts: $\{z:\Re(z^a+1)\leq 0\}$.

Is my conclusion right?
If so how to visualize the branch cuts explicitly?
Otherwise how to find the branch points and cuts of the said function?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $a \in (1,3/2)$ then there is a branch of $\sqrt{z^a+1}$ analytic on $\Bbb{C}-[0,\infty) - [e^{i\pi/a},e^{-i\pi/a}]$